# PHP5: how to Check & Set pre-defined canonical URL as header location via redirect 301?

Tags: php, apache, redirect

Im stuck with a common mistake of duplicate content that I want to solve:
A hyperlink in the browser shows: `http://website.org/nl/amsterdam`

Now, thats not the canonical URL and I would wish to have the webpage redirect to its known canonical url (on the condition that the current page is not already the canonical page)

```
<?php $canonical = "http://website.org/nl/amsterdam-grass-is-greener;

  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
  header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
  header("Location: " . $canonical);  // shows below picture, while url looks good

  exit(0);

<html><head><link rel="canonical" href="<?=$canonical?></head>...</html>
```

**Main Question: How to get this to work?** Currently the non canonical url seems to wanna direct to the canonical url (tested via HEAD info) but once it arrives there PHP gets stuck and shows:

[image]

**Minor Question: Does this idea sound good to you?** Since search engines do not use canonical so strictly and only use it as a hint, often saving the wrong, non canonical url. Does the above rule make it more strong via the 301 redirect for search engines to save the good versions in search results? Does this also solve my duplicate content url problem?

Comment: Not sure whether it solves the problem, but you need to send only the `Location` header: A `30x` status code will be sent automatically.

Comment: With using `exit` the HTML after it will never be returned to the client. Besides that, the [relation “canonical”](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139066) is meant for something different.

Comment: @Pekka, interestingly and indeed: my Apache Fedora answers a 30x but to be more precise says this: `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` when no 301 is set. when set it says `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` any conclusions from this to be drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(isset($canonical) && ('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $canonical)) {
  header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: ' . $canonical);
  exit();
}
```

To answer your more general question, this is not a tenable solution (unless your site is very small) because it requires you to hard code the canonical URL of every page. As near as possible, you should aim to create a URL structure that only has one URI per resource. However, it does solve the immediate problem of search engines perceiving duplicate content.

**Edit:** Thanks Gumbo.

Comment: As `$canonical` is an absolute URI and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is only the URI path and query, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $canonical` will always be true.

Comment: +1 Gumbo, you nailed the essence of the problem why I think @Dae 's answer does not work yet. Dae +1 for your initial answer albeit not working yet...

Comment: `("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $canonical)`  @Gumbo and @Dae, I figured out, basing on your both answers that probably the second premisse should be this. Is that right folks? This seems to work juiiippieiieieie !!!   Thanks very much! Love and Peace from Holland!

Answer (score 1):

It seems canonical tries to redirect too.
You have to use some HTTP sniffer to see what ACTUALLY happens when you press some button. Get yourself one like LiveHTTPHeaders Firefox add-on of whatever else and see what redirects being made.

Comment: +1 thanks @Colonel  but, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/  not available for FF 4 :(

Comment: @Sam: So what? Aren’t you willing to install Firefox 3 to test this?

Comment: @Gumbo, I just upgraded the other day to FF 4 and behold enjoyed the promised 6X faster (as FF said... which I think is true) and to go back in time just seems not elegant solution. Perhaps there are other ways to test what a link does. And so I found a free tiny tool called `ViewHEAD 1.05` by pc-tools.net  wich works perfectly on Windows 7 (and for those not having Windows, I guesse your advise would be: So what: Aren't you willing to install windows to test this?  So you can see my point: not elegant...